# Consuming httpOnly cookies from Postman

Tags: postman, session-cookies, cookie-httponly

Is there a way of defining a **httpOnly cookie** in **Postman** and send it to the client is requesting it?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

In version `7.3.5-canary04` onwards in the [Canary build](https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/canary) of Postman, you can programmatically set `cookies` from a pre-request script.

You would *need* to add the Domain to the whitelist before sending the request, once that's been added, you could use any of these methods to add the cookie to the request.

```
const jar = pm.cookies.jar();

// using cookie name and value
jar.set('http://example.com', 'token', '123456', function (error, cookie) {
  // error - <Error>
  // cookie - <PostmanCookie>
  // PostmanCookie: https://www.postmanlabs.com/postman-collection/Cookie.html
});

// using set-cookie string
jar.set('http://example.com', 'token=123456; Path=/; HttpOnly;', function (error, cookie) {
  // error - <Error>
  // cookie - <PostmanCookie>
});

// using PostmanCookie or its compatible object
jar.set(pm.request.url, { name: 'token', value: '123456', httpOnly: true }, function (error, cookie) {
  // error - <Error>
  // cookie - <PostmanCookie>
});
```

[image: Postman Cookies]

More information can be found here:

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3312#issuecomment-516965288

Answer (score 0):

Include the Cookie in Postman:
Open Postman and go to the request you want to modify. In the request headers, add a new header with the key Cookie and the value as your cookie.

For example:

Key: Cookie
Value: your_cookie_name=your_cookie_value